# Python Requests POST error: __init__() takes 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, api, post, flask, python-requests

So I have a Flask application which uses the Flask-Restless and Flask-SQLAlchemy modules to create an API. My GET requests are working fine, but POST requests are not.

From models.py:

```
from application import db

class User(db.Model):
    __bind_key__= 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(80))

    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email
```

From application.py (API setup):

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import flask.ext.restless
db = SQLAlchemy(application)

manager = flask.ext.restless.APIManager(application, flask_sqlalchemy_db=db)
manager.create_api(User, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Requests processes GET requests to the API fine, but when I have a POST request like this:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'http:<ip>:<port>/api/user'
data = {'email': '1234@here.com'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR in views [X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_restless\views.py:413]:
need more than 1 value to unpack
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_restless\views.py", line 409, in extract_error_messages
    left, right = str(exception).rsplit(':', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I know it has something to do with the json'd email data I'm sending, but I'm having trouble finding out what it wants exactly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the *full traceback* of the exception?

Comment: `requests` handles sending JSON natively now; you can do `requests.post(url, json=data)` to encode `data` to JSON before sending and the Content-Type header will be set automatically for you.

Comment: Otherwise your `requests` code looks *just fine*. I think this is a Flask-side problem, nothing to do with `requests`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I had to get the latest version of requests to use the json shortcut but when I did, Flask-Restless threw an error:        `ERROR in views [X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_restless\views.py:413]:
need more than 1 value to unpack
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_restless\views.py", line 409, in extract_error_messages
    left, right = str(exception).rsplit(':', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: That sounds a very different error, and looks incomplete somehow.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it didn't give the full traceback either, just the most recent call. Have no idea why it threw this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

Under models.py:

```
def __init__(self, email):
```

Email (as well as any other model's params) need to have =None

```
def __init__(self, email=None):
```

After that, this code works

```
import requests

url = 'http:<ip>:<port>/api/user'
data = {'email': '1234@here.com'}
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
```